# Include modules in racket

Tags: racket

I created a module (game.rkt) in Racket in which there is my game logic; in this file I define several variables, functions, threads...

I need to embed that module inside another one (gui.rkt) and start the game (game.rkt) from gui.rkt.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **gui.rkt**: You need to `provide` the definitions you want other modules to be able to use. Definitions aren't visible outside the module, by default. If you've defined functions `foo` and `bar` that you want to provide: `(provide foo bar)`.
- **game.rkt**: `(require "gui.rkt")`.

This assumes files are in the same directory.

For more details see the Guide sections about [`require`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-require.html) and [`provide`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/module-provide.html). Both have a number of options -- Racket's module system is one of its strongest features -- but the simple case is simple.